# Use mysql instead hsql java spring

Tags: java, mysql, spring

I hava this codes and i use application.properties for use mysql but yet hsql is use.

application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/dvv
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.platform=mysql
```

and application.class

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackageClasses = {VideoRepository.class, VideoRepository2.class})
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan



public class Application {

    // Tell Spring to launch our app!
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
        }   

}
```

and Repository

```
@Repository
public interface VideoRepository2 extends CrudRepository<Video2, Long>{

    // Find all videos with a matching title (e.g., Video.name)
    public Collection<Video2> findByName(String title);

    // Find all videos within a given category
    public Collection<Video2> findByCategory(String category);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you verify,

1.Check **how many** application-XXX.properties files are exists in your application.

2.Check whether you are using **correct** **profile** to run this application.

Also share your hsql configuration as well.

Comment: @SundararajGovindasamy tnx for your help :). I have just one app.pro in my app. and I dont understand what is correct profile that you said.

Comment: @aliishabazii, if you are having 2 property files one for dev and another for QA environments, for example application-dev.properties and application-qa.properties. Then, you need to tell the server which properties file ( or which profile to use ) to load. Can you check where you configured hsql in your application?

Answer (score 0):

make sure the mysql connector is added to your pom.xml /build.gradle

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>mysql</groupId>
  <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
</dependency>
```